# External screen flickering (22.04)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi, intel

External screen flickers on and off (image is present and then signal is lost, and then image appears again, flickering is random, but very often, ~3 times in 10 seconds) on a fresh installation.
Details:

- I'm using a laptop (ASUS GL552VW) with external monitor connected via HDMI. The HDMI port is connected to my iGPU, Intel HD 530 (there is no way to make that HDMI work with NVIDIA GTX 960M in my laptop).
- Nothing was installed after installing the OS - i connected to the Internet while installing the system and marked the option to download the updates.
- I had that issue on Windows 10 - I fixed it by installing a latest Intel GPU driver from laptop manufacturer's (ASUS) site, uninstalling drivers installed by Windows - they were the latest Intel drivers. Since then external screen works fine on Windows.
- Internal screen works fine.
- If I mirror external and internal monitor, external isn't flickering, but internal monitor's resolution is lower that external's one.

I'm a linux noob, so If you need some additional info - I will send it, just ask.

Comment: Try to use the X11-Server instead of wayland. Log out and select "X11-Server" (or similar) by pressing on the little cog in the lower right corner of the login screen

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 external monitors connected to an Intel nuc7 and have been unable to use more than one due to this flickering problem. Finally kernel 6.1.8 seems to have fixed the problem.